# SVG Scaling Giant in Internet Explorer, works in Chome(AngularJS)

Tags: html, css, angularjs, internet-explorer, svg

I've been having an issue I can't get my head around, I've tried many different fixes, mostly around `viewBox 0 0 x x` various `width=""` and `height=""` modifications (removing width and height, which I never had  in the first place).

Basically, I use Angular ng-nepeat to construct a row of SVG of specific colour, this is deployed in a propriety visualisation website (PIVision) which deploys HTML pages as draggable resizable objects. I don't think thus has anything to do with the issue but the information may have been helpful.

In Chrome, my HTML symbol shows up nicely as so : [Nice SVG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28AJR.png)
In IE however, the symbol shows up huge, and does not resize or scale as can be seen on the container resize box : [IE's SVG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGucN.png)

Below is my HTML, as I do not believe it to be a scripting issue, however if required I have attempted to create a JSFiddle (however doesn't work properly, I believe it is to do with my Angular JS set up in JSFiddle, as the implementation the company uses is prebuilt and slightly different, apologies).

HTML :

```
<div ng-style="{'height': config.Height, 'width':config.Width}" style="cursor:pointer" >
<table style="height:100%; width:100%">
    <tr style="width:100%; height:100%" id="theTableRow">
        <td ng-attr-title="{{getSortedValue($index)}}" ng-style="{'width':theCircleWidth + '%', 'padding':'0.3%'}" ng-repeat="n in config.makeCounterArray(config.columnMax) track by $index">
            <svg ng-if="sortedListOfValues[$index].elementName.charAt(0) == 'P'" style="filter:url(#dropshadow);" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 100 100">                   
                <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" ng-attr-stroke="{{config.stateColours[getSortedValue($index)]}}" stroke-width="4" ng-attr-fill="{{config.stateColours[getSortedValue($index)]}}" />
            </svg>
            <svg ng-if="sortedListOfValues[$index].elementName.charAt(0) == 'H'" style="filter:url(#dropshadow);" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 100 100">              
                <rect height="100" width="100" ng-attr-stroke="{{config.stateColours[getSortedValue($index)]}}" stroke-width="4" ng-attr-fill="{{config.stateColours[getSortedValue($index)]}}" />
            </svg>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>     
</div>
```

Is it possible to fix this or will I have to resort to using coloured `border-radius` div's to accomplish what I want?

Thanks in advance for any help given, apologies for anything wrong with the question, this is my first!

EDIT : After changing the table to include `table-layout:fixed` it scales a bit better, however I have this strange space above the table, link in first comment.

Comment: Having the same issue with angular `<mat-icon svgIcon="...">` now... and of course some customers insist on still using ancient IE so we can't just ignore it.

Comment: Seems the issue was the style was set to `display: table`. Your question gave me a hint that tables might be the culprit, and a change to `display: block` fixed everything :)

Answer (score 0):

SVGs are subject to CSS when directly embedded in the document, different browsers just have different default rendering.

Try this:

```
svg {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

For a new default styling. Resize them as needed in specific cases.

Comment: Thank you, will try now, however I have tried `table-layout:fixed` after learning this affects how SVG's are displayed in a table in different browsers, and have some level of success, will edit main post. EDIT : Link after `table:layout` https://imgur.com/a/RufCp

Comment: Hi, so tested this fix earlier this morning, unfortunately doesn't work, however I believe the issue is actually with how IE handles SVG's/tables. Thanks anyway